# In emacs, how to force switch to a different buffer in a dedicated window?

Tags: emacs

Is there a command or shortcut to force to replace the buffer in a dedicated window with another buffer?

When trying to switch to a different buffer using `C-x b` or `M-x switch-to-buffer` it says `"Cannot switch buffers in a dedicated window"`.

So, I need a way to either un-dedicate the window (which was opened as dedicated by some applications such as gdb) or be able to switch to a different buffer on that same window using shortcuts or overrides.

Answer (score 4):

Evaluating `(set-window-dedicated-p (frame-selected-window) nil)` should un-dedicate the current window.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dedicated-Windows.html for documentation on dedicated windows.

Comment: But how do you input this command? Trying "M-x" and "M-:" doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Onye You can evaluate the expression by running the `eval-expression` command (bound to `M-:` by default) and then typing the expression. It is unclear what exactly isn't working for you.

Comment: Nevermind. I was just doing something wrong. It works. Thanks for your help.